# Convert Excel Cell date in to specific format but it's always apply local date format not the format I am applying

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am using EPPlus, and my local date format is yyyy-mm-dd.

From a C# object, I am getting a value as strDate = 2023-03-14 10:41:59.483.

Now, I want to convert this date into mm/dd/yyyy and display it in an Excel cell.

Note: In the cell, I want to show the date as 03/14/2023, and in the formula bar, I want to show the full date as 03/14/2023 10:41:59 AM.

I used the below code to achieve this:

```
 if (value is DateTime dateTimeValue && dateTimeValue != DateTime.MinValue)
                        {
                            cell.Value = dateTimeValue;
                           cell.Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy"; 
                            
                       }
```

However, the issue is that it's showing the date with hyphens (-) instead of slashes (/).
In the cell, it's showing 03-14-2023, and in the formula bar, it's showing 03-14-2023 10:41:59 AM. I want the date to be displayed with slashes (/) instead - . Am I missing something, or is there a way I can achieve this? Thank you

Comment: Your question contains ambiguous information. In one sentence you wrote **_"Now, I want to convert this date into mm/dd/yyyy and display it in an Excel cell"_**, and then you wrote **_"In the cell, I want to show the date as 2023/03/14"_**. So, what you really want to see in the Excel document cell?

Comment: The problem might be that your value is a string rather than a date serial. Excel formats are display settings. Dates in Excel are stored as numbers. Your example date would be stored as: 44999.4458217593.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I also remember faintly that "/" may be just be replaced by whatever the local date separator is. You might have to force it, if you want a specific separator char.

Comment: @Jackdaw Just Updated now thanks for correcting I want date into mm/dd/yyyy